# Pull data from a database that has a similar name to "x"

Tags: php, mysql

I am calling my database to display on the page in a table. Currently i have a field called model where i list the different models of firearms. Ex. (Dt-11 Sporting,  Dt-11 Sporting Left handed)

I am currently having a issue were it will not pull up all the requested info.

```
mysql_select_db("premiumguns") or die(mysql_error());
$make ='DT-11 Sporting';
if (isset($make)) {
$query = "SELECT Serial_No, Make, Model, Gauge, Barrel_Length, Price FROM PG_inv WHERE Model like '" . $make . "' ORDER BY PG_inv.Price";
}
else
{
$query = "SELECT Serial_No, Make, Model, Gauge, Barrel_Length, Price FROM PG_inv ORDER BY PG_inv.Price";
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())
```

As far as i am aware the Where Model like should pull all rows that have a model containing "DT-11 Sporting" Which should include the "Dt-11 Sporting Left Handed" described above. But when the page is loaded only fields containing exactly "DT-11 Sporting" are displayed. Am i missing something?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter if you use = or like if you do not put any wild cards in your query

I have added % both sides of your search term so it will now search for items like "blah blah Term blah blah"

```
$query = "SELECT Serial_No, Make, Model, Gauge, Barrel_Length, Price FROM PG_inv WHERE Model like '%" . $make . "%' ORDER BY PG_inv.Price";
```

`LIKE "FOO"` is the same as = "FOO"`where as`LIKE "FOO%" will say anything starting with FOO

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT Serial_No, Make, Model, Gauge, Barrel_Length, Price FROM PG_inv WHERE Model like '%" . $make . "%' ORDER BY PG_inv.Price";
```

Damn it, beaten to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$make ='DT-11 Sporting';
```

to

```
$make ='DT-11 Sporting%';
```